# How to use File.text() in jest?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have some problems to make some tests pass. After a few hours lost trying to figure out what is going on, I have realized that jest has some problem with `Files`

I have wrote a simple test, to expect over a file content:

```
describe(".file test", () => {
    test("jest can work whit files", async () => {
      const aContent = "a_content";      
      const file = new File([aContent], "aFile.txt");
      const fileContent = await file.text()
      expect(fileContent).toBe(aContent)
    })
 )
```

That simple code, work when is executed in the real aplication within a browser. However, when I launch the test suite, I just get an error:

> TypeError: file.text is not a function

```
  30 |       const aContent = "a_content";
  31 |       const file = new File([aContent], "aFile.txt");
> 32 |       const fileContent = await file.text()
     |                                      ^
  33 |       expect(fileContent).toBe(aContent)
```

So, what I need to jest can work with Files?

Comment: There is a way. Mock `File`. `text` has been recently added and shouldn't be expected to exist in JSDOM.

Comment: I don't want to mock `File.text` because, in the real tests, I need that function returns the actual content of the file. If I use `mockImplementation` it will hide the actual behaviour of the application, and also, multiple files are readed in the subject under test, so it has to return different content each ime.

Comment: I see no problems with multiple files. Jest spy can be provided with new implementation each time you need it. Jest's DOM shouldn't and can't behave like real thing. It's Node.js environment with fake DOM, not a browser. If you want to test how it really works, use headless browser (Puppeteer).

Comment: Are you looking for unit testing, integration testing, or E2E testing?

Comment: I am looking for unit testing. However I came with a workaround thanks to @EstusFlask comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a workaround thanks to @EstusFlask comments.

I have mocked `File.prototype.text` to return the file object itself. Then I can read its content on test with a `FileReader`.